# Vue-Route and Axios don't work together in the same page

Tags: vue.js, axios, vue-router

I'm trying to use axios and router in the same time by using CDN, so I have these following codes that create an error when I try to run my webpage, I've been searching the whole day but couldn't help myself with it, I would appreciate if anyone has an idea.

```
<script src="https://npmcdn.com/vue-router/dist/vue-router.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/axios/0.19.2/axios.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.6.11/vue.min.js"></script>

      <script>
    new Vue({
          el: '#app',
          data() {
            return {
              listHotels: {},
              hotel: {
                name: '',
                price: 0,
                location: ''
              }
            }
          },
          methods: {
            getHotels() {
              axios.get('/database.json')
                .then(res => {
                  this.listHotels = res.data.hotels.data;
                });
            },
            addHotel() {
              if (this.hotel.name === '' || this.hotel.price <= 0 || this.hotel.location === '') {
                return alert('BOOOO ERROR');
              }

              const data = { ...this.hotel };
              axios.post('/hotels.php', data)
                .then(res => {
                  console.log(res.data);
                  this.getHotels();
                });

              this.hotel.name = '';
              this.hotel.price = 0;
              this.hotel.location = '';
            }
          },
          created() {
            this.getHotels();
          }
        });

    const Foo = { template: '<div>foo</div>' }
    const Bar = { template: '<div>bar</div>' }

    const routes = [
      { path: '/foo', component: Foo },
      { path: '/bar', component: Bar }
    ]

    const router = new VueRouter({
      routes // raccourci pour `routes: routes`
    })

    const app = new Vue({
      router
    }).$mount('#app')
    </script>
```

The error I have :

```
A cookie associated with a cross-site resource at http://cloudflare.com/ was set without the `SameSite` attribute. A future release of Chrome will only deliver cookies with cross-site requests if they are set with `SameSite=None` and `Secure`. You can review cookies in developer tools under Application>Storage>Cookies and see more details at https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5088147346030592 and https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5633521622188032.
```

Also, when I remove one of these code, axios or route, then it works.

Comment: Why are you creating two separate Vue instances?

Comment: Is there a way to put both in the same one ?

Comment: Get rid of the second `new Vue` entirely, move the first `new Vue` down to the bottom in its place and then pass `router` as a config option, along with all the others.

Comment: All right, thank you !